# Return values from jquery dialog loaded via ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, dom

I'm hoping for some insight into something which WAS working, now isn't and I can't understand why.

This is using asp.net in VB and jquery.

I have a page on which I have an appointment selection screen, the screen displays a list of branches and the number of available appointments per branch using a repeater.

Upon clicking one of the blocks with the stated number of appointments, jquery calls another .aspx page via ajax passing across the branch and date.  This page uses these to generate a form to display the dates.  The HTML returned via ajax is then used to populate the HTML element of a div which is displayed as a JQuery dialog.

Within this dialog is a link for each available time, upon clicking the link a textbox called time_selected is filled with "[" & Selected_Time & "]" and a textbox called time_id is filled with "|" & Select_Booking_Slot_ID & "ǁ"

In the initial loading of the dialog we have the close event which obtains the HTML of the dialog (Including the textboxes) and parses it using the delimiters surrounding the date and ID to get the information we need.

Now I stress that this WAS working on one instance of the page, I have gone to create a mobile version of the same page and it no longer works... also going back to compare to the original I find the original no longer works.

The HTML returned no longer contains the contents of the textboxes that has been appended.

Here is the code for loading the selection page and putting it into the dialog with the close event which is in the main page.

```
        $("a.showslots").click(function () {
            $("#<%=bookingslot_branch.ClientID %>").val($(this).attr('branch'));
            $("#<%=bookingslot_date.ClientID %>").val($(this).attr('date'));
                       $.ajax({
                           url: "appointment_select_small.aspx?slots=" + $(this).attr('id') + "&date=" + $(this).attr('date') + "&branch=" + $(this).attr('branchtext') + "&branchid=" + $(this).attr('branch'),
                           context: document.body
                       }).done(function (data) {
                           $("#Slots").html(data);
                           $("#Panel_Slots").dialog({
                               modal: true,
                               resizable: false,
                               close: function (event, ui) {
                                   var data = $("#Panel_Slots").html();
                                   var test_str = data;

                                   var start_pos = test_str.indexOf('[') + 1;
                                   var end_pos = test_str.indexOf(']', start_pos);
                                   var text_to_get = test_str.substring(start_pos, end_pos);

                               var start_pos1 = test_str.indexOf('ǀ') + 1;
                               var end_pos1 = test_str.indexOf('ǁ', start_pos1);
                               var text_to_get1 = test_str.substring(start_pos1, end_pos1);

                               if (text_to_get.length != 0) {
                                   $("#<%=bookingslot_time.ClientID %>").val(text_to_get);
                                   $("#<%=bookingslot_id.ClientID %>").val(text_to_get1);
                                   $("#<%=btn_bookingslot_click.ClientID %>")[0].click();
                               }
                               //$(this).remove();
                               return false;
                           }
                       }).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
                       $("#Panel_Slots").dialog('open');
                       $("#Panel_Slots").position({
                           of: window,
                           my: "center center",
                           at: "center center"
                       });
                   });
                   return false;
               });
```

And then here is the code in appointment_select_small.aspx

```
                $("a.bookappointment").click(function () {
                $("#time_selected").val("[" + $(this).attr('id') + "]");
                $("#time_id").val("ǀ" + $(this).attr('bid') + "ǁ");
                $("#Panel_Slots").dialog('close');
                return false;
            });
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Where and when is the code in appointment_select_small.aspx called?

Comment: I have just noticed that when developing this my Visual Studio was hooked into IE9 for debugging but my IE was displaying IE7 Standards as the Document Mode.  I'm going to run through some validation in the hope that, that will solve my issues.  Hang on to your lunch pales...

Comment: Whua... debugging with IE! Horrible experience. Only good thing is the profiler to observe massive javascript ressource needs.

Comment: Okay I've come to the conclusion that this should never have worked.  So now I'm looking at new ways to actually get the data embedded in the DOM so that when I get the $("Body").html() it returns the data I need.  I'm tried appending the values in a div into the body but it still just returns the original body as loaded without the appended data.  I've switched to firefox and am using firebug.

Comment: This is now solved, I was really confusing the issue by trying to add extra elements to the DOM then trying to read it.  I've find the bind function in jQuery and so following the ajax load, I'm binding the events to the newly created A tags, and I'm pulling the properties I need directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is now solved, I was really confusing the issue by trying to add extra elements to the DOM then trying to read it. I've find the bind function in jQuery and so following the ajax load, I'm binding the events to the newly created A tags, and I'm pulling the properties I need directly.